# making integers from a given set

Tags: recreational-mathematics

this Q is very easily generalizable. For example consider $1,2,3$ and $4$. We have $1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=4+1, 6=2\times 3, 11=4\times 3-1$. You can only use each number once. 37 is the first number not achievable. Does 1,2,3,4 form an optimal set?

EDIT: Optimal: Assuming I'm right about 37, is there a ($n=4$) set which lasts for longer, e.g. 1,3,4,7 works till 40?

Comment: optimal in which sense?

Comment: What operations are allowed?

Comment: assuming i'm right about 37, is there a set which lasts for longer, e.g. 1347 works till 40? (n doesn't have to be 4)

Comment: @Travis; +-/*() - ^ if you must

Comment: Wait.. $37=4\cdot3^2+1$

Comment: @hkmather802; now try without ^

Comment: Are you asking for more "optimal" $n=4$ set? Or you are seeking for more examples?

Comment: @hkmather802; i've answered this question in my head, unfortunately I have no proof that 1,2,3,4 is optimal